# Which layout is currently used Landscape or Portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, multi-window

I am facing a issue which i need to resolve by making my view intelligent about what type of view is used currently.

I have two layout one for Portrait and another for landscape(land).

- MyFragmentLayout.xml
- MyFragmentLayout.xml *(land)*

I am currently setting my child View of the Fragment with some Padding and i want the view to know which type of layout is currently in use.(Portrait/Landscape).
This is my code i used:

```
 val verticalPadding = if (context.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

            TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50f, displayMetrics)

        else

            TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150f, displayMetrics)
```

Above work's perfectly for orientation change case.

**Problem:**

I am giving Multi-Window support to my application And the issue i am facing is when **Window** is in portrait mode (i.e orientation is Portrait)

But application due to region available switches the layout from portrait mode to landscape mode.

[image: ScreenShot]
As you can see the upper window with red bar is in Portrait mode but Application use's it's Landscape Layout.(which is perfect for my case)

**I want to know how can know which type of layout is currently used by my application independent of the current Orientation of the mobile.**

Comment: ;D negative vote i don't think person got the context of question. Please read question then vote.I tried to search a lot and i found no solution.thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the best approach but you may give to your layouts different containers ids and search for those ids in onViewCreated method.

For example

- MyFragmentLayout.xml:

```xml
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/portraitContainer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

- MyFragmentLayout.xml (land)

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/landscapeContainer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Then, in your onViewCreated method:

```java
View v = view.findview(R.id.portraitContainer)
if (v !=null){
  // portrait layout loaded
} else{
  // landscape layout loaded
}
```

Let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: The problem is that i have my Fragment initiation in separate Module which is not accessible to My Child View. And i won't prefer this approach as code will be fragile then. Thanks btw it would have worked for sure.but looking for better approach.

Answer (score 0):

My Current Solution for this problem is as below.

I have created:

- `dimens.xml`          (/values folder)
- `dimens.xml`*(land)*  (/values-land folder)

To store the `Padding Dimension` for different type's of layout(portrait and landscape).

```
val verticalPadding = context.resources
                             .getDimension
                             .getDimension(R.dimens.vertical_padding)
```

This is the best approach i found. I am looking for a better approach which i can control by `JAVA/Kotlin` code and ***not by separate xml files***

In Above Solution when Application choses to use **MyFragmentLayout.xml (land)**
(Landscape layout) then automatically Application take's dimensions from ***dimens(land)***